# angular 2 update app component from router outlet component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm using angular 2 rc1 and the new router @angular/router

In app component I have a nav section and router outlet

```
<nav>   
    <a *ngIf="auth?.userName == null" [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
    <a *ngIf="auth?.userName != null" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
    {{auth?.userName}}
</nav> 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I inject a loginService into app component and subscribe to an event in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loginService.loginSuccess.subscribe(this.loginSuccess);

} 
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.loginService.loginSuccess.unsubscribe();
}
private loginSuccess(res: IAuthResponse) {
    this.auth = res;
}
```

when I navigate to my '/login' route page/component my loginService is inject and loginService defines an event

```
@Output() loginSuccess = new EventEmitter<IAuthResponse>();
```

and after successful login in my service, the login service raises the event

```
this.loginSuccess.next(response);
```

I'm able to set a breakpoint in app component on the subscribed loginSucess and the data is passed along, however 'this' is undefined.

```
private loginSuccess(res: IAuthResponse) {
    this.auth = res;  //this is undefind
}
```

how can I update the app component from events that are triggerd from services used in components that are hosted in the router outlet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "and the data is passed".

```
@Output() loginSuccess = new EventEmitter<IAuthResponse>();
```

in the component added by the router (`LoginComponent`) doesn't do anything. 
`@Input()` and `@Output()` in routed components are not supported.

Just inject `LoginService` to the routed component and emit the event using an observable in the login component.

```
@Injectable() 
export class LoginService {
  changes:BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);
}
```

```
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private loginService:LoginService) {}

  onLogin() {
    this.loginService.changes.next(true);
  }
}
```

```
export class NavComponent {
  constructor(private loginService:LoginService) {}

  onLogin() {
    this.loginService.changes.subscribe(status => this.isLoggedIn = status);
  }
}
```

Comment: I do inject loginService into the loginComponent and the loginService has the @output eventEmitter defined.  When the event is raised from the login service, the app component receives the event with data (IAuthResponse) but 'this' in app component is null/undefined

Comment: Ok, `EventEmitter` should only be used in components. `@Output()` in a service is meaningless. Do you have `function()` instead of `()=>` anywhere in your code or do you pass a function around anywhere?

Comment: changing @output() EventEmitter from my service to a SubjectBehavior resulted in the correct behavior I was looking for.  thanks for the clarification of when/where to use the output attribute.

Comment: Great! Ok, then in the end the `Behavior' part made the difference. `EventEmitter` is a `Subject` (without `Behavior` and the Angular team might change the implementation to something different eventually). The difference is that `BehaviorSubject` immediately emits the last event to new subscribers while with `Subject` subscribers only get events that are emitted after they subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could be the solution to my problem:  passing events from child to parent that uses router-outlet, however it looks like RC1 has changed how BehaviorSubject works.  Using the method above:

```
changes:BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

gives an error saying BehaviorSubject needs a type declaration, so I tried both

```
changes:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    as well as
changes:BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

and it compiles fine, but when running the app, it gives a non-descriptive
error of:

```
zone.js:323 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/index.js
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
at SystemJSLoader.__exec
(http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1395:16)
at entry.execute
```

I'm assuming something has changed with rxjs and BehaviorSubject

Comment: That's not related to `BehaviorSubject` itself. The first error message is some configuration settings about static type checking (I don't know details here because I'm using Dart myself). The 2nd error message also is related to your project setup. Please don't add follow-up questions as answers. Rather create a new question with a link to the one you are extending on.

Comment: I found out what it was, they moved the location of the BehaviorSubject.  It was previously under rxjs/subject/BehaviorSubject, now its in rxjs/BehaviorSubject, that fixed it.   Also, they (Stackoverflow) doesn't let me add a comment to other posts because I need a 500 rating or something like that, but they allow answer posts...go figure