# How to listen to events as part of router configuration?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an app with a a login component and a home component and once the user has logged in I'd like to navigate to the home component. I'd like the login component to emit a 'login successful' event after authenticating, and the app component to listen to that and navigate accordingly, but I can't see how to add the event listener in the rooting configuration.

Most of the examples I have seen involve the navigating happening within the login component, but this feels like it breaks the idea of self contained components, as the login component will need to be aware of the home component and also the rooting structure of the app.

I'd like to use the output of the login component, but I can't see how to do this when navigating to the login using router configuration.

`<login (loginSuccess)="handleLoginSuccess($event)"></login>`

There was also a lengthy discussion on github (https://github.com/angular/router/issues/185) that suggests navigating to sibling roots isn't recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your login component output is the authorization data, you can use [angular guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) to handle the behavior.

Comment: This will achieve the desired effect, but surely having the login component being responsible for navigating breaks the idea of having reusable components. I wouldn't be able to use this approach to create a login component I could share across different apps

Comment: The login component won't be responsible for the navigating, it will only be   linking the route path. router should be responsible for the navigating and the guard.service will be checking if the user has the correct authentication

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a [shared service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) to communicate between the home and login components, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192619/angular-2-update-app-component-from-router-outlet-component?rq=1) answer.

If the goal is just to re-use the login component, you could pass the url you want to redirect to after successful e.g. '/home' via route data.

In your route definitions:

```
...
{ 
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent,
  data: {
    onLoginOk: '/home'
  }
}
```

And in LoginComponent ..

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {    

onLoginOk: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.forEach((data: { onLoginOk: string }) => {
      this.onLoginOk= data.onLoginOk;
    });
  }
...
```

So the LoginComponent knows nothing of the home component, it just knows that when it logs in successfully, it navigates to some URL.

Comment: This is definitely an improvement, but its not entirely satisfactory because if, at a later date, I want to add another action upon successful log in, I'll need to edit the login component again

Comment: Yep that's a fair point. I think the best option is then to use a service as described by Gunter in the linked question.